# Свойства-расширения в C#

Tags: c#, .net, extension

Возможно ли сделать свойство-расширение для класса?
Например у меня есть такой метод-расширение:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string Normalize(this string str)
    {
        return str.Trim().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Используется он так: `user.NormalizedName = user.Name.Normalize();`

Я хочу использовать его так: `user.NormalizedName = user.Name.Normalized;`

Comment: Смысл? Сэкономить пару скобок? Attached Property можно сделать (да и они есть в WPF, например), но без синтаксической поддержки пользоваться ими будет неудобно

Comment: @mirypoko дело вкуса, на мой взгляд `entity |> M1 |> M2 |> M3` читается еще лучше

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Нет, свойства как расширения в C# не поддерживаются, возможно в будущих версиях будут, обсуждения по этому поводу проходят. На данный момент расширениями могут быть только методы.

Comment: Можете оставить ссылку на обсуждения, если уж их упомянули? Было бы интересно почитать =)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/192 К примеру, у еще можете посмотреть ссылки на другие Issues в нем. Вообще идеи довольно интересные.

Comment: Это да, спасибо!